# Intel Processor Family

Tags: cpu

What does Intel refer to as "Processor Family"?

I found out that a processor family is a grouping of processors with similar features,
as stated at: [the VMware Sphere documentation](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.vcenterhost.doc%2FGUID-0E98521D-9663-42C0-AE48-37501F2E138C.html)

So correct me if I am wrong, Intel refers to his processors families as beeing part of these categories?

- Intel® Core™
- Intel® Xeon®
- Intel® Atom™
- Intel® Quark™
- Pentium®
- Celeron®
- etc.

Comment: http://www.intel.com/pressroom/kits/quickreffam.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Intel's use of the term "processor family" (e.g. ["About Intel® Processor Numbers"](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-numbers.html), it refers to a more specific classification than Xeon, Core, Atom, or Quark (i.e., each of those can have multiple "families"). It seems to be used *roughly* such that each new generation/chip design (excluding minor changes, steppings)—whether from a microarchitecture change (e.g., Sandy Bridge, Haswell) or a change in manufacturing process (e.g., 32nm, 22nm)—introduces a new processor family.

Celeron and Pentium appear to be used as "class" names, though [this page](http://www.intel.com/products/desktop/processors/celeron.htm) seems to use "Intel® Celeron® Processor Family", "Intel® Pentium® Family", and "Intel® Core® Family" in a more general sense. I *think* this is just an eliding of "current generation", i.e., "processor family" still refers to a more specific category.

Even within a processor family, there is not complete binary compatibility. E.g., Core i5-4430 does not support TSX-NI (transactional memory extension) while Core i5-4570 does, yet both are part of the 4th generation Core Processor Family. In addition, processors in different families and even different "classes" can have complete binary compatibility since Xeon and Core use the same microarchitecture for the processing core.

Based on  ARK urls (e.g., `http://ark.intel.com/products/family/75026/#@All`) i7, i5, and i3 (and mobile variants) are considered different sub-classes with each generation introducing a new "family".

So it would appear that the classification system begins at the "class" level (Xeon, Core, Atom, Quark) and can have an intermediate sub-class (e.g., i7, i5, i3) and finally each class or sub-class can have multiple "families" introduced across time with changes in design or manufacturing. The broadest classes distinguish general targeted use (Xeon for servers/workstations, Core for mainstream personal computers, Atom for low-end personal computers and embedded, Quark for low-end embedded). More specific classes make distinctions based generally on budget/performance (e.g., i7 class processors are higher performance than i5 *in general* for a specific generation and Xeon can be divided by how many sockets are supported)

More specific than the "processor family" is the stock keeping unit (SKU), i.e., processor number, which can vary in features disabled, cache size, core count, frequency, and thermal design power.

Since "processor family" is a marketing term, the definition does not have to be perfectly clear and consistent. Basically, **a processor family is a group of SKUs of a particular generation within a broader class**.

---

It might also be worth noting that Intel previously used "Itanium Processor Family" to refer to the Itanium *architecture*. Intel uses "series" rather than "family" in marketing Itanium. From a marketing standpoint not only does that avoid confusion with the earlier use of family for the Itanium architecture but also fits the more technical market that Itanium targets and even implies continued progress.

Answer (score 0):

The image you linked refers to virtualization software - a sandboxing environment for software development.

Pertaining to "Processor Family" in this context, this the various instruction sets that you are seeking to emulate in your virtual CPU (such as [SSSE3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSSE3) and [SSE4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4)).

This will enable your developed software to be built and tested on such platforms.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe my questions was misleading with that link. My question is what does Intel refer to as "Processor Family" in the context of a real processor?